# Excel: extrapolating data by group into the same column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, statistics

I am trying to extrapolate baseline age into the remainder of the columns, for each participant.

See here, it's much clearer:

[image]

Essentially, I need to put `45` into the remaining `ID = 40` rows, and ditto `39`. This is for a large number of participants otherwise I'd just do it manually!

Thanks!

Comment: Is the baseline age already inserted for the first of each ID?

Answer (score 0):

If the first of each baseline age is already filled, you can use this quick and dirty way:

1. Select the column `C2:C11` (or whatever range your data covers) then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and select <kbd>Special...</kbd> > "Blanks" > OK.
2. Press `=` (without touching anything else) and push the up button.
3. Now, do **NOT** press <kbd>Enter</kbd> but press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. After this, you should see that all the cells should be nicely filled up. Select the whole of column C, copy, and paste as values to remove the formulae so that there's no problem when you filter or do other operations.